# Reduce time in finding duplicate user based on condition in large data set

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, caching, duplicates

We have over 1000 million customer data in MySql and indexed in ElasticSearch. 
Customer data includes email(up to 5 alternate emails), Phone(Upto 5 alternate phones), name, Date of birth, etc. 
Whenever a new customer comes We need to find if that customer already exists with us based on the newly entered email or Phone or combination of name and date of birth.

**Condition for duplicity** - Email OR (Name and Phone) OR (Name and DOB)

**Example-**
Existing customer A-
Email - 1@a.com,2@a.com,3@a.com,4@a.com,5@a.com
Phone - 1,2,3,4,5
Name- A
DOB - 1/1/2001

a new customer tries to come-
Email - 99@x.com,98@x.com,97@x.com,**1@a.com**,96@x.com
Phone - 99,98,97,96,95
Name - B
DOB- 1/2/2001

Condition for duplicity - Email OR (Name and Phone) OR (Name and DOB)
Since Email 1@a.com matches so, the new users would be marked duplicate.

Elasticsearch query, in this case, is a bit slow for large and sharded dataset and taking around 1.5sec. This is a realtime system and so, needs to reduce this time.

One possible alternative approach was to keep every email, phone and name+DOB combination in the cache(aerospike/Redis). But, in this approach, we need to check the cache for at least 11 times(5 emails,5phones,1 name+dob) which is also heavy operation I mean 11 HTTP calls.

We tried finding more and better approaches but unable to figure out, can anyone suggest an approach for the use case.

The Elastic query for finding duplicate-

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [{
                                "bool": {
                                    "must": [{
                                        "bool": {
                                            "should": [{
                                                "bool": {
                                                    "must": [{
                                                        "terms": {
                                                            "EMAIL": ["99@x.com","98@x.com","97@x.com","1@a.com","96@x.com"]
                                                        }
                                                    }]
                                                }
                                            }, {
                                                "bool": {
                                                    "must": [{
                                                        "match_phrase": {
                                                            "NAME": "B"
                                                        }
                                                    }, {
                                                        "terms": {
                                                            "PHONE": ["99","98","97","96","95"]
                                                        }
                                                    }]
                                                }
                                            }, {
                                                "bool": {
                                                    "must": [{
                                                        "match_phrase": {
                                                            "NAME": "B"
                                                        }
                                                    }, {
                                                        "terms": {
                                                            "DATE_OF_BIRTH": ["2001-02-01"]
                                                        }
                                                    }]
                                                }
                                            }]
                                        }
                                    }]
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }]
        }
    },
    "size": 50,
    "from": 0,
    "_source": ["CUSTOMERID"],
    "sort": {
        "_score": "desc"
    }
}
```

Comment: At this scale, professional help is advised.

Comment: Additional information request. 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Please post current Query(s), EXPLAIN SELECT (your query(s)); SHOW CREATE TABLE tbl_name; for each table used in the query.

Comment: @WilsonHauck as mentioned in the question We do not query MySQL for the purpose of finding duplicate, Instead we use Elasticsearch. I have added the query in the question above.